# Teradata - Max value of a dataset with corresponding date

Tags: sql, teradata

This is probably obvious, I just can't seem to get it to work right.  Let's say I have a table of various servers and their CPU percentages for every day for the past year.  I want to basically say:

"for every server name, show me the max CPU value that this server hit (from this dataset) and the corresponding date that it happened on"

So ideally I would get a result like:

server1 52.34% 3/16/2012
server2 48.76% 4/15/2012
server3 98.32% 6/16/2012
etc..

When I try to do this like so, I can't use a group by or else it just shows me every date:

select servername, date, max(cpu) from cpu_values group by 1,2 order by 1,2;

This of course just gives me every server and every date..  Sub-query? Partition by?  Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `row_number()` OLAP window function:

```
   select   servername
          , cpu
          , date 
   from     cpu_values
   qualify  row_number() over (partition by servername
                               order by cpu desc) = 1
```

Notice that you do not need a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause. The PARTITION clause is similar to a GROUP BY and the ORDER BY clause sorts the rows within each partition (in this case by descending cpu).  The "=1" part selects the single row that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery would be the simplest solution:

```
SELECT
    S.Name, Peak.PeakUsage, MIN(S.Date) AS Date
FROM
    ServerHistory AS S
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            ID, MAX(CPUUsage) AS PeakUsage
        FROM
            ServerHistory
        WHERE
            Date BETWEEN X AND Y
        GROUP BY
            ID
        ) AS Peak ON S.ID = Peak.ID
GROUP BY
    S.Name, Peak.PeakUsage
```

P.S., next time around, you may want to tag with "SQL".  There are relatively few Teradata people out there, but plenty who can help with basic SQL questions.

Comment: Added SQL tag to question. ;)